# characteristic-$p$-type groups, and the Borel-Tits theorem for $PSL(V)$

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups

If $G$ is a finite group and $F^*(G)$  is the generalized Fitting subgroup we say that $G$ has characteristic $p$ ($p$ is a prime that divides $|G|$) if 
$$F^*(G)=O_p(G)$$

Moreover $G$ is a characteristic-$p$-type group if all its $p$-local subgroups have characteristic $p$.

I need some reference for this argument, in particular I need a proof of the Borel-Tits theorem which asserts that $PSL(V)$ is a characteristic-$p$-type group if $V$ is a vector space over the finite field $\mathbb F_{p^k}$.

Many Thanks in andvance

Comment: Near duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351074/a-problem-about-normalizers-in-pslv

Comment: I actually started writing up a proof of this for myself (back in summer '12 apparently). I think it's a very interesting result. Did you ever write it up? I'll try to piece together an answer from my notes. I recall reading a few proofs, and basically constructing one using flags.