# A problem about normalizers in $PSL(V)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, geometric-group-theory

Let $K=\mathbb F_{p^k}$ a finite field, and $V$ a vector space on $K$. Clearly $PSL(V)=SL(V)/SL(V)\cap Z$  acts on $V$ by the following rule ($Z$ is the subgroup of the scalar functions):

$$v^{(SL(V)\cap Z)\gamma}:=\gamma(v)$$

this action is well defined, and if $W$ is a proper subspace of $V$

$$N_{PSL(V)}(W):=\{x\in PSL(V)\,:\, w^x\in W\quad\forall w\in W\}$$

Such normalizers are the *maximal parabolic subgroups*. Now I have the following problem that is making me go crazy:

> If $T$ is a maximal parabolic subgroup in $PSL(V)$ and $O_p(T)$ is its $p$-radical (i.e. the maximum $p$-supgroup in $T$ that is normal), show that
>   $$C_T(O_p(T))\le O_p(T)$$

The above statement is equivalent to saying that every maximal parabolic subgroup of $PSL(V)$ has characteristic $p$.

If $Q$ is the $p$-radical of $N_{GL(V)}(W)$, up to this moment I've showed only that $C_T(O_p(T))\le C_{PSL(V)}(Q(SL(V)\cap Z)\big/(SL(V)\cap Z))$.

I've found nothing in literature about the above problem.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your "action" of ${\rm PSL}(V)$ on $V$ is not well-defined unless ${\rm SL}(V) \cap Z = 1$. It would be easier to consider the action of ${\rm SL}(V)$ on $V$ and prove that $C_T(O_p(T)) \le O_p(T)({\rm SL}(V) \cap Z)$. In ${\rm SL}(V)$, the group $T$ just consists of block matrices with zeros in the top right block, so it is easy to study it.

Comment: You are right, the faithfull action of $PSL(V)$ is on the projective geometry $PG(V)$ not on $V$

Comment: If you are really looking for a detailed analysis of the structure of the geometric-type maximal subgroups of the classical groups, then you should look at the book "The subgroup structure of the finite classical groups" by Kleidman and Liebeck.